# Python - loop through csv file and check next line

Tags: python, csv

I want to loop through a csv document and often check the next row for values, but stick to the same row number. The .next() is skipping a row, which won't work for me, unless I could go back again somehow. Is there a simple way in doing this? I tried the pairwise/cycle but it takes way too long if the file is big. 
My sample code is:

```
file1 = open("name.csv", 'rb')
reader = csv.DictReader(file1)
new_rows_list = []

for row in reader:
    if row['IsFixated'] == 'TRUE':
        new_row = [row['Result'], 'Fixation']
        new_rows_list.append(new_row)
    else:
        new_row = [row['Result'], 'Saccade']
        new_rows_list.append(new_row)
        nextRow = reader.next() # check for next row ??
        if nextRow['IsFixated'] == 'TRUE':
            new_rows_list = CheckPreviousPositions(new_rows_list)

file1.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
reader1,reader2 = itertools.tee(csv.DictReader(file1))
#this creates two copies of file iterators for the file
next(reader2) #skip first line in second filehandle
for line,next_line in itertools.izip(reader1,reader2):
    #do something?
```

I guess ... maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to check the next line this generator function should do the trick

```
def next_reader(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        check = 0
        curr_and_next = []
        while True:
            if check == 0:
                first = reader.next()
                second = reader.next()
                curr_and_next = [first, second]
                check = 1
            else:
                curr_and_next = [curr_and_next[1], reader.next()]
            yield curr_and_next
```

This opens up your file and add the first and second line to the `curr_and_next` list and returns it. In any subsequent call it will move the second value in curr_and_next into the first spot and then add the next line in the file into the second spot.  Now instead of yielding one row at a time, this generator will yield a list containing the next row and the row following it.  For example if you have a csv file alpha.csv with the rows:

```
a,b
c,d
e,f
```

and you have a loop:

```
for x in next_reader('alpha.csv'):
    print x
```

this will print:

```
[['a','b'],['c','d']]
[['c','d'],['e','f']]
```

Note that the last line in your csv file will only appear once in the very last iteration. (You won't get something like `[['e','f'],None]` for the last print).